# How to add "or" in my method?

Tags: java

I have following code that determines the user's language.

```
    if (locale.equalsIgnoreCase("eng")) {
        ....
    } else {
        ....
    }
```

I want to add "or". For example:

```
    if (locale.equalsIgnoreCase("eng" OR "fra")) {
           ....
```

Syntax is incorrect because I don't know how to do that. Help, please.

Thank you all for the quick answers.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Comment: Seeing as you're new to Java, I recommend you have a look through the [summary of operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
locale.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") || locale.equalsIgnoreCase("fra")
```

Comment: Nah, that's not my style. Enjoy your +2 :)

Comment: upvote the fastest cheapest scavenger of a contributor, is this what we do here? >_< i ll hunt you, find you in seven hells of stackexchange and downvote u both.

Answer (score 6):

You can get an easy OR in java by doing:

```
if (this || that) {...}
```

So, in your case, it would be:

```
if (locale.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") || locale.equalsIgnoreCase("fra") {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (locale.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") || locale.equalsIgnoreCase("fra"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (locale.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") ||  locale.equalsIgnoreCase("fra")) {
    ...
```

Easiest way I could think of right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (locale.equalsIgnoreCase("eng") || locale.equalsIgnoreCase("fra")) {
    ....
} else {
    ....
}
```

Easy!